# Validation for email or phone number for same text field in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am working on registration form for my project in AngularJs. Users can register with his/her Email/Phone. I need to validate that particular text-box.

I have validations for both, with different text fields, with ng-pattern. But how can I validate for both in one text field?

I have updated my code, here:- `enter code here`
http://plnkr.co/edit/mCVxHxl2DIvqOYtVapRN?p=preview

Comment: Use a regex that is combines the two regexes with an or: `/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,5})$|^\d+$/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/^([_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,5}))|(\d+$)$/`

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZN3vKWzPylXw4KBSvYBe)

Comment: Phone number min limit or max limit is not working

Answer (score 3):

You can use a pipe '|' to OR two regular expressions together:

```
/<email-pattern>|<phone-pattern>/
```

so your final regex would be:

```
/^([_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,5}))|\d+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular form validation and ng-pattern directive for input use `ng-pattern="/^(?:\d{10}|\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})$/"`

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/3y4kcqsj/4/)**

```js
var app = angular.module("MY_APP", []);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.submitted = false;
  $scope.submit = function(userData){
   console.log(userData)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MY_APP">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="userForm" novalidate ng-submit="userForm.$valid && submit(userData)">
              <div class="errorMsg" ng-show="submitted==true && userForm.$invalid">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-show="submitted==true && userForm.emailphone.$error" class="errorMsg">
                            wrong format, It should be email or 10 digit mobile number
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    <input type="text" name="emailphone" ng-model="userData.user" id="emailphone"  required
    ng-pattern="/^(?:\d{10}|\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})$/" />
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted = true">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think so this is the wrong email `sanat.gupta@gmail.com` but getting the wrong email from your function.

Answer (score 1):

guys here is the Regex for email or phone number Please have look I hope it's helpful.

Thanks

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})|(^[0-9]{10})+$
```

Here is an example as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/sanat/b2m436L5/17/

```js
function validate(){
    var value = $("#email_phone").val();
  
  var regex = new RegExp('^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})|(^[0-9]{10})+$');
  
  if(value){
         if(!regex.test(value)){
          $("#error").text("Please enter valid email address or phone number.")
       }else{
         $("#error").text('')
       }
  }else{
    $("#error").text('This field is required.')
  }
    

}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
#error{
  font-size:14px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
   <div>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Email/phone" id="email_phone">
    <button onClick="validate()">Submit</button>
    
   </div>
   <span id="error"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This code might work for you: Here is the ans of your question 
<script type="text/javascript">
            function validate(){
                var phoneNo = document.getElementById('txtEmailormob');
                var c=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
                var atpos=c.indexOf("@");
                var dotpos=c.lastIndexOf(".");
                var errorMsg = document.getElementById("errorMsg");
                var successMsg = document.getElementById("successMsg");

                if(phoneNo.value==""||phoneNo.value==null){
                errorMsg.style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "Please enter your Mobile No or Email  ";
                    return false;
                 }
                if ((phoneNo.value.length < 10 || phoneNo.value.length > 10) && (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=c.length)) {
                errorMsg.style.display = "block";
                successMsg.style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "  Mobile No. is not valid, Please Enter 10 Digit Mobile No or Please Enter valid Email. ";
                return false;
            }
                successMsg.style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("successMsg").innerHTML = " Success ";
                errorMsg.style.display = "none";
                return true;
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code

Complete Working Like Validate : amazon, Facebook, uber.etc  Email or Phone Number Using Single Input...

Try this its working ..............

```
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#cuntryCode").hide();
            $("#useridInput").on('input', function () {
                var len = $("#useridInput").val().length;
                if (len >= 2) {
                    var VAL = this.value;
                    var intRegex = /^[1-9][0-9]*([.][0-9]{2}|)$/;
                    if (!intRegex.test(VAL)) {
                        $('#error-caption').html('Invalid email. Please check spelling.');
                        $('#error-caption').css('color', 'red');
                        $("#cuntryCode").hide();
                    } else {                    
                     if(len < 10){
                        $('#error-caption').html('Invalid mobile number. Please try again.');
                        $('#error-caption').css('color', 'red');
                        $("#cuntryCode").show();
                      }else{
                        $('#error-caption').html('Invalid mobile number. length must be 10 digit.');
                        $('#error-caption').css('color', 'red');
                    }
                  }
                }else{
                   $("#cuntryCode").hide();
                   $('#error-caption').html('');
                }

            });             
        });

    </script>



<form class="push--top-small forward" method="POST" data-reactid="15">
            <h4 id="input-title" data-reactid="16">Welcome back
            </h4>
            <label class="label" id="input-label" for="useridInput" data-reactid="17">Sign in with your email address or mobile number.
            </label>
            <div style="margin-bottom:24px;" data-reactid="18">
              <div >
                <div id="cuntryCode" class="_style_4kEO6r" style="float: left; height: 44px; line-height: 44px;">
                  <div tabindex="0" > +241
                  </div>                      
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex;">
                  <input id="useridInput" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" name="textInputValue" class="text-input" placeholder="Email or mobile number" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="error-caption input-title">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="error-caption">
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn--arrow btn--full" data-reactid="24">
              <span class="push-small--right" data-reactid="25">Next
              </span>
            </button>
          </form>
```