# AngularJS : email or phone number validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-pattern

**Expectation :**

I am working on login form in Angular. Users can login with **Email/Phone**. I need to validate the Email/Phone in single text-box.

**Live Scenario :**

Facebook implemented same type of functionality in login. we can login in Facebook via **Email/Phone**. But as per the research Facebook validates the user data by performing server side validations not the client side validations.

**Tried so far :**

```js
function validate() {
  var textBoxValue = document.getElementById('emailphone').value;
  var emailPattern = /^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?@[a-z][a-zA-Z-0-9]*\.[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?$/; 
  if(textBoxValue == '') {
    alert('Please enter value');
    return false;
  } else if(isNaN(textBoxValue)) {
    if(!(textBoxValue.match(emailPattern))) {
      alert('Please enter valid email');
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    if(textBoxValue.length != 10) {
      alert('Please enter valid phno');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="emailphone" id="emailphone"/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate" onclick="validate()">
```

I am able to achieve this functionality using pure JavaScript but I want to implement it in Angular using **`ng-pattern`** or if there is any work around in Angular.

**I found this post on SO but not working as per my expectation**.

[Validation for email or phone number for same text field in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776182/validation-for-email-or-phone-number-for-same-text-field-in-angularjs)

Comment: https://codepen.io/rpdasilva/pen/DpbFf My favorite phone directive.  Not perfectly applicable in your case, but it might help to take a look.

Comment: What did you find is "not working per [your] expectation" in that other question's answers? Because that's pretty close to an exact duplicate of this question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan validation not working as per my expectation. When i am trying to type alphabet it shows me a wrong error message that phone number is not valid as i am trying to input email.

Comment: If you want validation on keystroke, it won't know if you're entering a email or a phone number. Add `ng-model-options="{ 'updateOn': 'blur' }"` if you want validation to occur when they leave the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use angular form validation and ng-pattern directive for input
use `ng-pattern="/^(?:\d{10}|\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})$/"`

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/3y4kcqsj/4/)**

```js
var app = angular.module("MY_APP", []);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.submitted = false;
  $scope.submit = function(userData){
   console.log(userData)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MY_APP">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="userForm" novalidate ng-submit="userForm.$valid && submit(userData)">
              <div class="errorMsg" ng-show="submitted==true && userForm.$invalid">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-show="submitted==true && userForm.emailphone.$error" class="errorMsg">
                            wrong format, It should be email or 10 digit mobile number
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    <input type="text" name="emailphone" ng-model="userData.user" id="emailphone"  required
    ng-pattern="/^(?:\d{10}|\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})$/" />
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted = true">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this, we can use `NgFormControllers` and `validators` to validate a form in angularjs. Below code helps you to enter correct email or phone while typing and before submitting the form. `ng-if="form.emailphone.$error.pattern"` in this, `form` is name of the form and `emailphone` is the name of the input field and `$error` is the holder of failed validations. `$error.pattern` will be true until the input matches the expression in the `ng-pattern`

```
<form name="form">
     <input type="text" name="emailphone" ng-model="email" ng-pattern="/^([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?@[a-z][a-zA-Z-0-9]*\.[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?)|[7-9][0-9]{9}$/" >
     <span ng-if="form.emailphone.$error.pattern">Enter correct email or phone number!</span>
</form>
```

`ng-model` is mandatory. Otherwise it won't work. Because it is `undefined` until the `pattern` matches.
As you know, **validate forms before submitting them for better user experience**

Comment: Please read my question again. I need to validate the Email/Phone in single text-box not only Email.

Comment: Just write the correct pattern for both. That's it. I also mentioned in the answer

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle link.In your answer i am only able to email validation message. How it will work with Phone.

Comment: Now my question is how i will display the seperate error message for mobile and email with same ng-pattern ?

Comment: I dont know why you want to display two messages for single input. Just try to display `enter correct email or phone number`. Or you can have a name that refer both like, `username`

Comment: But if user type number like "9" . it would be a number or email also. So, how it will be distinguish ?. i dont want to display any error message when user type any numeric or alphanumeric digit on first index

Comment: a email never start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use angular form validators among with the ng-pattern directive.

```
<form name="userForm">
    <input type="text" name="emailphone" ng-model="userData.user" id="emailphone" ng-pattern="/(^[0-9]{10,10}$)|(^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?@[a-z][a-zA-Z-0-9]*\.[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+))?$/" />
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" ng-click="validate()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Once you name your form you are able to use the validators from it. 
`userForm.$invalid` will be true in case it detects an invalid input inside the form. Then, with the directive `ng-disabled` you could disable the button.

Since we added the `ng-pattetrn`, it will be true unless the input match the ng-pattern regular expression.

Another thing to know is that the ng-model value: `userData.user` will be undefined unless it matches the regular expression

Comment: I need to validate the Email/Phone in single text-box not only Email.